# AD Design for SME with Oversea Branch

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, exchange

Our company is a SME with global presence. The HQ is in Singapore, with branch in Taiwan, China, Malaysia, Europe and US. However, the distribution of staffs in these place is uneven. Singapore, Taiwan and China account for 90% of the total headcount, whereas Malaysia, Europe and US only account for about 10%.

For security purpose, our company intended to implement AD. Since I am quite new to AD, I am currently stuck on a few questions waiting for your clarification:

My current design is creating one forest and many domain controller, with each domain controller corresponds to one branch. however, some branch such like the ones in malaysia and europe have only a few staffs. So should I still create one dedicated domain controller for such branch?
We intend to set up AD server only in Singapore but not other place, will this design cause latency to oversea users? In what situation should I set up AD server in other branches as well? Which approach is recommendable to our company?
Is VPN necessary for oversea staffs to use AD service(e.g. authentication) and exchange service in HQ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to be specific without knowing the exact physical and logical layout of your company's sites and networks, but in general you should have at least one, if not two domain controllers in each AD site, which should encompass one or more geographically-close installations.

Regarding VPN, you should not be exposing your AD infrastructure publicly, so sites would be connected via VPN tunnels or leased lines (MPLS etc).  Remote workers can use a client-based VPN to access the network as required.

This question is likely a bit too localized to your particular situation.  The broader question you really should be asking is "What factors should I take into account when designing an international, multi-site AD topology?"

Answer (score 2):

> My current design is creating one forest and many domain controller, with each domain 
>   controller corresponds to one branch

Start by reading the documentation. A Domain Controller is a domain controller - unless you make that multiple domains in a forest (may be a good idea, may be not - serious adminsitrative overhead) they are identical except those having special roles). As in each DC stores all the data. They are GC (Global Catalogs) or not.

> So should I still create one dedicated domain controller for such branch?

Well, you should NEVER EVER have one domain controller for anything - what if that machine dies? TWO is the minimum, 3 for a non small operation. Double redundancy. See this as a lesson in beginner administrator thinking.

That said, I would put 2-3 DC in every location - if needed virtualized.

> We intend to set up AD server only in Singapore but not other place, will this design 
>   cause latency to oversea users?

Yes. It will. It also will wreak havog on the other locations if the internet is down for some reason, and it WILL Fail. Microsoft inttroduced recently RODC (Read Only Domain Controllers) to act as local caches in remote offices.
A small computer is not that expensive, can act as local cache and file server, print server etc.

> Is VPN necessary for oversea staffs to use AD service(e.g. authentication) and exchange 
>   service in HQ?

No, it is not NECESSARY. You can put all machines on the public internet and they can use it without VPN. This has serious security (negative) implications, and would be a fireable offense in many companies.

Otherwise yes, it is standard to connect offices with a VPN Setup, which often is handled by the routers of the offices so it is totally transparent to the user (and totally irrelevant to AD etc.)

Given that these are pretty basic questions I would suggest hiring someone with more experience to help you with the planning and implementation of this environment - you will get into a lot of trouble and make some questionable decisions with your level of knowledge.  Working with an experienced professional will let you learn The Right Way to do things without causing problems for your company in the process.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the IPD (Infrastructure Planning and Design) guide for Active Directory back to back, it will answer all of your questions. You can find it here:

http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/B/C/5BC966BC-47D8-41DF-95F2-FA9A2D816258/Active%20Directory%20Domain%20Services.zip